# How do I POST HTML Form Data coming from an externally hosted webpage to a Data Extension on Salesforce Marketing Cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, httprequest

I am trying to create a custom form on my organization's webpage, NOT a salesforce cloud landing page. How do I get this form to POST up to a SFMC data extension. Smart Capture Forms seem to only work if being used on a cloud landing page, but for my purposes I need the form to be native to our organizations webpage. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 6):

There are a couple of different options.

You could use Email Studio Web Collect. https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_es_email_studio_web_collect.htm&type=5

It's basic and and has a number of limitations.

Alternatively for a more robust options that includes more control over updates you can use the REST API. 
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/postDataExtensionRowsetByKey.htm

There is also a SOAP API that you could also use. 
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/web_service_guide.htm

Another slightly more creative method could be to create a CloudPage code resource containing AMPScript or SSJS and have your website POST to that endpoint.